# What URL do I use to PXE boot over http with CentOS 7 dvd?

Tags: centos, pxe-boot

I have this mount on my nginx server:

```
/home/msh/CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1503-01.iso on /usr/share/nginx/www/iso type iso9660 (ro,relatime)
```

so the root of the iso file system is one step in from the nginx document root. So when I load http://192.168.10.2/iso in a browser, I see:

```
../
EFI/                                               27-Mar-2015 22:34                   -
LiveOS/                                            27-Mar-2015 22:34                   -
Packages/                                          31-Mar-2015 23:42                   -
images/                                            27-Mar-2015 22:34                   -
isolinux/                                          27-Mar-2015 22:34                   -
repodata/                                          31-Mar-2015 23:43                   -
CentOS_BuildTag                                    31-Mar-2015 23:45                  16
EULA                                               27-Mar-2015 22:36                 215
GPL                                                27-Mar-2015 22:36               18009
RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7                               27-Mar-2015 22:36                1690
RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-Testing-7                       27-Mar-2015 22:36                1690
TRANS.TBL                                          31-Mar-2015 23:50                2883
```

My question is, with the CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1503-01.iso distribution, what url do I use in /var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux/default ? 
Thanks.

Comment: Search for kernel file ending in vmlinuz and file containing initrd

Answer (score 2):

from [Serva's](http://vercot.com/~serva/an/NonWindowsPXE3.html) website for CentOS 7.X

```
 kernel   = /NWA_PXE/$HEAD_DIR$/images/pxeboot/vmlinuz
 append   = initrd=/NWA_PXE/$HEAD_DIR$/images/pxeboot/initrd.img root=live:http://$IP_BSRV$/$HEAD_DIR$/LiveOS/squashfs.img ksdevice=bootif repo=http://$IP_BSRV$/$HEAD_DIR$/
```

in your case would be

```
root=live:http://192.168.10.2/iso/LiveOS/squashfs.img  repo=http://192.168.10.2/iso/
```

please consider you also have to edit the TFTP retrieved file paths depending on where your TFTP server root directory is pointing to.
i.e if your TFTP Service uses iso/ as root then you should consider

```
kernel   = /images/pxeboot/vmlinuz
append   = initrd=/images/pxeboot/initrd.img ....
```